# Longest consecutive sequence in Binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement the logic for "Longest consecutive sequence in Binary tree". The logic I have implemented inside the method { longestConsecutivePath } is not working as expected for the tree structure. It is giving me the lognest path length as 5.
Output:
curLength : 5

```
    BSTNode node = new BSTNode(1);
    node.setRight(new BSTNode(2));
    node.getRight().setRight(new BSTNode(3));
    node.getRight().getRight().setRight(new BSTNode(4));
    node.getRight().getRight().getRight().setRight(new BSTNode(5));

    node.getRight().setLeft(new BSTNode(7));
    node.getRight().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(8));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(9));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(10));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(11));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(12));
```

Class implementing the Longest Consecutive sequence logic:

```
public class LongestConsecutivePath {

static BSTNode root = null;

public LongestConsecutivePath() {
    root = createBinaryTree();
    System.out.println("Before finding the longest consecutive path:");
    inorder();
}

public void inorder() {
    if (null == root) {
        return;
    }
    inorder(root);
}

private void inorder(BSTNode node) {
    if (null != node) {
        inorder(node.getLeft());
        System.out.print(node.getData() + " ");
        inorder(node.getRight());
    }
}

public BSTNode createBinaryTree() {
    BSTNode node = new BSTNode(1);
    node.setRight(new BSTNode(2));
    node.getRight().setRight(new BSTNode(3));
    node.getRight().getRight().setRight(new BSTNode(4));
    node.getRight().getRight().getRight().setRight(new BSTNode(5));

    node.getRight().setLeft(new BSTNode(7));
    node.getRight().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(8));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(9));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(10));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(11));
    node.getRight().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BSTNode(12));

    return node;
}

public int longestConsecutivePath() {
    if (null == root) {
        return 0;
    }

    return longestConsecutivePath(root, 0, root.getData() + 1);
}

public int longestConsecutivePath(BSTNode node, int curLength,
        int targetLength) {
    if (null == node) {
        return curLength;
    }

    if (node.getData() == targetLength) {
        System.out.println("\nnode data value: "+node.getData());
        curLength += 1;
        longestPath = curLength;
    } else {
        curLength = 1;
    }

    longestLeft = longestConsecutivePath(node.getLeft(), curLength,
            node.getData() + 1);
    longestRight = longestConsecutivePath(node.getRight(), curLength,
            node.getData() + 1);

    return Math.max(curLength, Math.max(longestLeft, longestRight));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LongestConsecutivePath consecutivePath = new LongestConsecutivePath();
    int curLength = consecutivePath.longestConsecutivePath();
    System.out.println("\ncurLength : " + curLength);
  }
}
```

BSTNode.java

```
public class BSTNode {

BSTNode left, right;
int data;

/* Default constructor */
public BSTNode() {
    left = null;
    right = null;
    data = 0;
}

/* Constructor */
public BSTNode(int data) {
    left = null;
    right = null;
    this.data = data;
}

public BSTNode getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(BSTNode left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public BSTNode getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(BSTNode right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public int getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(int data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and got the correct result. The logic looks good. It checks every possible path. Are you sure you're using this exact test case?

Comment: Hi @JaysonBoubin - with the current code and tree structure I should receive the output as 6 (Nodes are 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 respectively.)

Whereas, the output I'm getting is 5. So it is actually considering these nodes (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) from the tree structure.

have you modified the tree structure by any chance? Could you please let me know what is the output are you getting?